# How to group comma seperated columns into one single string in a unix for loop

Tags: unix, for-loop, awk

I am working with a pipe separated list(text file), which looks like

```
recipename|category|list_items
-------------------------------------------
veg_quesadilla|groupA|lettuce, spinach, beans
burrito_bowl|groupA|brown_rice, black_beans, lettuce, pepper
french_fries|groupB
beverage|groupC|pepsi
```

I have below statement

```
for recipename in `head -4 list_catalog.txt | awk -F "|" '{print $1}'`
do
if [ `cat list_catalog.txt | grep $recipename |  awk -F "|" '{print $3}'` != NULL ]
then
    for list_items in `cat list_catalog.txt | grep $recipename | awk -F "|" '{print $3}'`
do
echo -e ${list_items}
done
fi
done
```

In the first loop, i am iterating over each recipe name, and i am checking if the list_items exists for each recipe. If yes, then i want to print all the column seperated items as one string, instead of seperated items. I mean all the comma separated items (which starts after second pipe symbol) as one string

Like this:

```
lettuce, spinach, beans
```

Instead of:

```
lettuce,
spinach,
beans
```

And when i run the code i am getting error,

```
line 3: [: too many arguments
```

Not sure, if i am doing right with AWK or not. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with your code.

```
if [ cat `list_catalog.txt | grep $recipename |  awk -F "|" '{print $3}'` != NULL ]
```

Your command inside the command-substitution quotes starts with `list_catalog.txt` as if it's the command. You probably meant to put `cat` inside the command-substitution quotes. Maybe that was just a mistake as you typed this question into Stack Overflow, because it gives a different error than the one you reported.

```
myscript.sh: line 3: list_catalog.txt: command not found
```

Even if you fix that, it generates an invalid test. You can spot it if you run sh with debugging output:

```
$ sh -x myscript.sh
...
+ '[' lettuce, spinach, beans '!=' NULL ']'
myscript.sh: line 3: [: too many arguments
...
```

The words returned by your command substitution are not quoted, so they show up as separate words. You can't have three words as the left hand side of the `!=` operator.

To fix this, put the command-substitution inside quotes, so whatever it returns will be treated as one string.

```
if [ "`cat list_catalog.txt | grep $recipename |  awk -F '|' '{print $3}'`" != NULL ]
```

All that said, I can't tell why you're doing this at all. The input file already has your list_items on a single line, which appears to be your goal.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Karwin. That double quotes worked perfectly.I am actually new to unix and my list catalog contains 100 such lines and i am trying to generate an SQL query and hit the database. `select distinct ${list_items} from database.$recipename order by ${list_items} desc`. Though this solved my purpose, i am working to write better code. BTW, i corrected the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

@try:

```
cat script.ksh
recipe_name="etc"
awk -vrec_name="$recipe_name" -F"|" '($0 ~ rec_name) && $3{print $3}'  Input_file
```

Simply making field separator as | and checking $3 is present or not if yes then print $3 which means 3rd field.

Comment: careful with that condition, it doesn't JUST test for $3 being present. Think about it...

Comment: I just edited my code, as it was not clear from user's question so read user's code and edited it above now. Thank you for Ed for your reply.

Comment: I think you missed the point `$3{print}` will test for $3 being being presnet **and not equal to a value that evaluates numerically to zero**. If you just want to test for it being present that'd be `$3!=""{print}`. btw not putting a space between `-v` and `rec_name=` makes your script unnecessarily gawk-specific.